# Run time error [Teradata] The object name is too long in NFD/NFC

Tags: vba, teradata

When I try to run a SQL query through VBA Code it is throwing the below error:

> Run time error -2147467259(80004005)
>   [Teradata] The object name is too long in NFD/NFC

```
Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rec1.Open oSql, conn
Worksheets("BO_Output").range("A" & (N)).Value = thissql
```

My query is working fine when I run it in SQL assistant

Comment: What version of Teradata is your database, and what version of the driver do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when running an update query in SQL Assistant.  I had enclosed my text field in double quotes rather than single quotes.  Teradata interpreted the double quotes as a column name.  You might like to review your code and see that there isn't any way the quotes could be embedded in your VBA code.